# How to implement pagination to display the history message using pubnub?

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

With the limit parameter in ngHistory() we can retrieve that number of messages.
Is there any way to implement the pagination while loading the history message

```
PubNub.ngHistory( {
                    channel : $scope.channel,
                    limit   : $scope.limit, 
 });
```

i know about the startDate and endDate slice by need the requirement is based on to show based on the record number

Answer (score 1):

Does this reference from the regular JS docs help: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/storage-playback.html#_step_9_paging_through_messages ?

Comment: is there any solution to display the pagination with the number of record?

Comment: with start and end time how to slice between each start and end time in each pages say page 1,2,3?

Comment: @guny please contact us at support@pubnub.com, we want to get a better idea of your case, and we can see about providing a customized solution for you.

Comment: send mail to pubnub support